# heredoc variables between underscores

Tags: bash

Say I have something like this,

```
tee filename <<EOF
...
access_log /srv/users/serverpilot/log/$APP_NAME/$APP_NAME_nginx.access.log  main;
...
EOF
```

where `$APP_NAME` is a variable.

Bash interprets `$APP_NAME_nginx` as a variable and doesn't print any value there. How could I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
${APP_NAME}_nginx
```

This will make `bash` expanding the variable `APP_NAME` to its value and adding `_nginx` to it.

Here is a test:

```
$ APP_NAME=check
$ echo "$APP_NAME"
check
$ echo "$APP_NAME_var"

$ echo "${APP_NAME}_var"
check_var
```

Comment: by the way, how would avoid $something from being interpreted as a variable?

Comment: Just add a backslash escape at the start `\$something`